# Ubuntu gdb can't access memory at address when tryint to view memory at $esp

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, assembly, gdb, vmware-workstation

[image]

Hi,

I am running ubuntu on VMWARE and when i try to access the memory at $esp,I get the error as shown in the screenshot below.I've tried googling for answers but most of them were too complicated.

Is there any configuration I need to do for this to work?

I've tried running gdb on my actual windows machine and it does not have this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Since $esp would be the lower 32 bits of the full stack pointer have you considered that with 64 bits you really probably want to be looking at what is pointed to by **$rsp** instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `$rsp`, not `$esp`.

By using `$esp`, you got the sign-extended 32-bit-truncated value of `$rsp`, which points to neverland.

Note: GDB provides `$sp` pseudo-register that is automatically mapped to correct stack pointer register for a given platform.

```
(gdb) p $rsp
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe178
(gdb) p $sp
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe178
(gdb) p $esp
$3 = -7816
(gdb) p/x $esp
$4 = 0xffffe178
```